Relativistic movement of charged particles
Electrons are accelerated horizontally by a voltage of 17 kV. Then they pass a 2.7 cm long electric field which accelerates them vertically. Then the electrons reach a screen  22 cm away from the electric field and 11 cm above thir original height. The electric field should be calculated. Sketch
I only solved this problem neglecting relativistic effects.
But I struggle when it comes to taking the relativistic effects into account.
To get the horizontal velocity I solved the euqation for v: $$U q=m c^2 (\gamma-1)$$ with $\gamma= 1/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$. (U... voltage, q... elementary charge, m... mass of electron, c...velocity of light, v... velocity) So, the horizontal distance equals $x=v t$.
I am not sure how to get the velocity in y-direction. Neglecting relativistic effects, I would sole the following equation: $$E q=a m$$ (E... electric field strength (unknown), a...accelertation). Then I would get the distance in y-direction by integration twice.
Further, I calculateted the time when the electron reaches the end of the electric field by solving: $0.0027=v t_1$. With this time I calculated the distance in y-Direction after the electric field: $$y=Eq/2m t_1^2$$. I did the same thing with: $0.22=v t_2$ to get the time when it reaches the screen. Then the we get for the y-diretion $$y=Eq/2m t_1^2+Eq/m t_1 (t_2-t_1)=0.11$$. This can be solved for $E$.

However, the time that passes in x-direction does not equal the time that passes in y direction. So how do I get the time that passes in y-direction when the movement in both directions is relativistic? And how do I calculate the velocity in y direction taking into account that the mass increases with velocity?

Velocity does not cause the mass to increase.

The relativistic equation of motion of a particle with mass $m$ and charge $q$ in a time-independent external electric field $\vec{E}=-\vec{\nabla}\phi$ is given by $$\frac{d\vec{p}}{dt} = q \vec{E}=-q \vec{\nabla} \phi, \tag{1} \label{1}$$ where $$\vec{p}= \frac{m \vec{v}}{\sqrt{1-\vec{v}^2/c^2}} \tag{2} \label{2}$$ is the particle momentum. Multiplying \eqref{1} by $\vec{v}$, one finds $$\frac{d \mathcal{E}}{dt}= q \vec{E} \cdot \vec{v} \quad \Rightarrow \quad \mathcal{E}+q\phi = \text{const.}, \tag{3} \label{3}$$ where $$ \mathcal{E}= \frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\vec{v}^2/c^2}}= c \sqrt{\vec{p}^2+m^2 c^2} \tag{4} \label{4}$$ is the relativistic expression for the energy of the particle. Combing eqs. \eqref{2} and \eqref{4}, the velocity of the particle can expressed in terms of the momentum and the energy by $$\vec{v}=\frac{\vec{p} c^2}{\mathcal{E}}. \tag{5} \label{5}$$
Equipped with these basic tools of relativistic mechanics, it is now easy to solve your problem. Assuming that the electron is initially at rest, its energy at the end of the acceleration phase is given by (cf. eq. \eqref{3}) $\mathcal{E}= mc^2 + |e U|$ with $|U|= 17 \, \rm kV$ and $q=-e$. Assuming further that the electron is accelerated in $x$-direction, we have $p_y=p_z=0$ and $p_x$ determined by the equation $$c \sqrt{p_x^2 + m^2 c^2} = mc^2 +|eU|. \tag{6} \label{6}$$
For the motion of the electron in the second phase (deflection in $y$-direction with electric field $\vec{E}=- |E| \vec{e}_y$), we thus have the initial conditions $$ p_x(0)=\sqrt{e^2U^2/c^2+2|eU|m}, \quad p_y(0)=0, \quad p_z(0)=0, \tag{7} \label{7}$$ for the equations of motion (cf. eq. \eqref{1}) $$\frac{dp_x(t)}{dt}=0, \quad \frac{d p_y(t)}{dt}= |e E|, \quad \frac{d p_z(t)}{dt} =0 \tag{8} \label{8}$$ with solutions $$p_x(t)=p_x(0),\quad p_y(t)= |e E| t, \quad p_z(t)=0. \tag{9} \label{9}$$ Employing \eqref{3} together with \eqref{9}, we find $$y(t)= \frac{c\sqrt{p_x(0)^2+(eEt)^2+m^2c^2}-c\sqrt{p_x(0)^2+m^2c^2}}{|eE|}. \tag{10} \label{10}$$ Using \eqref{5}, we find $$\frac{dx(t)}{dt} = \frac{p_x(t) c^2}{\mathcal{E}(t)} = \frac{p_x(0) c}{\sqrt{p_x(0)^2+(eEt)^2+m^2 c^2}}. \tag{11} \label{11}$$ Integrating \eqref{11} with the initial condition $x(0)=0$, allows to establish the relation between the length $x(t_1)=x_1= 2.7 \, \rm cm$ and the corresponding time $t_1$, providing the necessary initial conditions for the final phase of a free motion to the detection screen. The remaining steps of the calculation are left as a homework exercise.
Remark: The time parameter used here is the one of the lab frame. We are not performing a Lorentz transformation to another inertial system. Thinking of different times "passing in $x$- and $y$-direction" is a misconception.
